# .Htaccess remove slash at the end

Tags: php, .htaccess

I need to add a rewrite rule, but automatically add the slash at the end, and I don't need it.

I use this rule:

```
RewriteRule ^print-res/([0-9+/=$]*)/([A-Za-z0-9+/=$]*)$ print-res.php?idreserva=$1&tkn=$2 [QSA,L]
```

If I go to this url, for example: `www.xxx.com/print-res/25/1kewnfd231`

httacces redirect me to: `www.xxx.com/print-res/25/1kewnfd231/`

And the tkn parameter its like: `1kewnfd231/`  Not  `1kewnfd231`

Who can I remove the last `/`?

Thanks!

Comment: Do the virtual paths orverlap with real directory structures? What does the RewriteLog say? Why did you presume this particular rule responsible?

Comment: I only work in some part of this code. The last rule, without tkn parameter was: ^print-res/([0-9]*)$/(.*)$ print-res.php?idreserva=$1 [QSA,L]. I try to add a tkn parameter only.

Comment: Can you show your full .htaccess because your current rule doesn't add a trailing `/` some other rule might be doing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the problem was specifically with that rule, you can try to rewrite it like this:

```
RewriteRule  ^print-res/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?$ print-res.php?idreserva=$1&tkn=$2 [NC,QSA,L]
```

It should change both `www.xxx.com/print-res/25/1kewnfd231` and `www.xxx.com/print-res/25/1kewnfd231/` to: `www.xxx.com/print-res.php?idreserva=25&tkn=1kewnfd231` (without the `/`).